# How can I access the var member inside anonymous class?

Tags: java

I suddenly found myself facing a problem:

```
public abstract class A {
  public int var = 0;
  public abstract void fun();
}

public class B {
  private A a;

  public B() {
    a = new A() {
      public abstract void fun() {
        // How to access A.var
      }
    };
  }
}
```

As the above comment goes: How can I access the `var` member? Or am I making mistake?

P.S. I'm not accessing containing class member (not B.this).

Comment: `a.var` would work, but that code won't compile since the `fun()` method cannot be declared abstract in the anonymous class. So, in class B, it is not `public abstract void fun() {` but rather `public void fun() {`

Comment: What's wrong with simply `var`? https://ideone.com/NE8Kye

Comment: Within the anonymous class implementation of `A`, using `this` references the instance of said implementation. In other words, using `this.var`, or simply just `var`, inside the `fun()` method override will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an anonymous class, you can use `this.var`, `a.var` or the variable `var` itself. Since it is an anonymous class you can access all its public or its package visible fields
Here's and example

```
abstract class A {
    public int var = 0;
    public abstract void fun();
}
class B {
    A a;
    public B() {
        a = new A() {
            public void fun() {
                System.out.println(var);
            }
        };
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().a.fun();
    }
}
```

In other cases where `a == null` or `a != this` you cannot use `a.var` for example

```
class B {
    A a;
    A a2;
    public B() {
        a2 = new A() {
            public void fun() {
                System.out.println(a.var);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You would end up getting a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Note that `a.var` only works because `a == this` in this case. However, it's possible for `a != this` in other contexts.